# Attribute Assistant-Dynamic Value Table-TableName Values- Expressions ValueInfo

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-assistant

I am having a problem populating an ID attribute "GISOBJID" which is a string in a versioned SDE data set. The AUTONUMBER I want to combine "ASSETID" works fine for everything , but I want to combine that with an ALPHA prefix (FM-123) into the "GISOBJID" attribute. I have tried several ways and no success. Only the AUTONUMBER works. I have tried using the full SDE name "UTILITIES2.CCU.ssPressurizedMain" in the DynamicValue Table and the shotened version "ssPressurizedMain" with no results. I have also tried an EXPRESSION "FM-" & Str( [ASSETNUM] ) and GenerateID with SSPRESSURIZEDMAIN|0|FM-[seq] still no success.

[image: GENERATEID Table Long Table Name]

[[image: DYNAMICVALUE Table GENERATEID longlayer name] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUO3H.png)

[[image: DYNAMICVALUE Table EXPRESSION short layer name] [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS8i2.png)